# Execute a stored procedure with multiple IDs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a `PersonInformation` table that contains the information below:

```
| PersonID | Name | Status  
+----------+------+------------
| 1234     | John | Active 
| 5678     | Mary | Inactive 
| 1090     | Tery | Active 
| 1554     | Cary | Inactive
```

I also have a stored procedure called `SpStats` that does some calculations using `PersonID` and returns the results of stat_a, stat_b.

I need to execute the `SpStats` stored procedure for each active person in the `PersonInformation` table using their `PersonID`.

It is basically

```
SELECT PersonId, Name, Status, {Exec SpStats for related PersonID} 
FROM PersonInformation  
WHERE status = 'Active'
```

The expected result is this:

```
| PersonID | Name | Status | stat_a | stat_b |
+----------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1234     | John | Active |   25   |   45   |
| 1090     | Tery | Active |   10   |   67   |
```

Comment: You can create a Function. Functions can be called in fields list.

Comment: Can you control the stored procedure?

Comment: that would need to be a scalar user defined function

Comment: @nyilmaz what is your DBMS ? and can you modify `SpStats` stored procedure ?

Comment: I can't control/modify the stored procedure.

Comment: You can't aply a Stored Procdure to each row. You can create an User Defined Function?

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a user defined table function that will do what your stored procedure does, you could use `cross apply` to get it's results for each row in the select.

Assuming it accepts the `PersonID` value, it can be done like this:

```
SELECT PersonId, [Name], [Status], stat_a, stat_b
FROM PersonInformation  
CROSS APPLY dbo.UDFStats(PersonID) as stats
WHERE [Status] = 'Active'
```

Note that `CROSS APPLY` will not work with stored procedures.

Comment: I have tried to create user-defined table function but could not able to do because there are a few temp tables in the store prod.

Comment: Can you create a new stored procedure to handle multiple persons instead of just one?

Comment: No, unfortunately. This store prod creates some statistical information for the given PersonID.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid without further information to go on, I can only offer you a [**RBAR**](https://sqlstudies.com/2016/08/17/rbar-vs-batch/) solution. I guess I don't have to tell you how bad it is.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom type like so

```
--Table Valued Parameter Type used for passing lists of Int IDs.
CREATE TYPE [MySchema].[UniqueIDListType] AS TABLE
(
    [ID] Int NOT NULL
);
```

Then in your stored proc set the input parameter to your type

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySchema].[MyProc]
    @MyIDList [MySchema].[UniqueIDListType] READONLY
AS
```

And there you go, you can use your parameter like a table in your select

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @MyIDList WHERE ID = PersonID);
```

You will get a full result set for each id then. Pass it in to the proc like you would any other parameter, you'll just need to format the ids into this single collection. And the bonus is you can reuse your new table valued parameter everywhere you need to do this again. Reusability!! Yay!

If you can't do this, then I'm assuming you can't with your requirements or permissions make a function either, I would then just loop through programmatically and make a table variable in your sql, call the proc for each person, insert that result in your table, and join that on your final select result set when you're all done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
     CountryId      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    
    ,Abbreviation   VARCHAR(10)
    ,Name           VARCHAR(100)
)
```

And a User Defined Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfConcatenate(@value1 VARCHAR(4000), @value2 VARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT(@value1, @value2)
    /* HERE YOU CAN EXECUTE YOU SOTRED PROCEDURE AND RETURN THE RESULT */
END
```

You can execute

```
select  c.CountryId, dbo.udfConcatenate(c.Abbreviation, c.Name) from country AS C
```

The User Defined Function can be applied for each row.
So, the User Defined Function execute you Sotred Procedure and return the result.
And, you use the User Defined Function in you SELECT.

**EDIT**

WHILE way

```
DECLARE @abb VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(200)

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT Abbreviation, Name FROM Country 

OPEN cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @abb, @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT dbo.udfConcatenate(@abb, @name)

    /* HERE YOU CAN EXECUTE THE SP AND STORE THE RESULTS IN A TEMP TABLE */

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @abb, @name
END

CLOSE cur1
DEALLOCATE cur1
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I have received this error message. **Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.** I have a few temp tables in the store prod.

Comment: In a UDF you can use TABLE type (variable) to temp tables. You can alter the procedure? Something is wrong. You can't aply a SP to each row. Why you need this?

Comment: A alternative is use a WHILE to execute the PROC to each row of an SELECT.

Comment: This store prod creates some statistical information for the given PersonID. It consists of many joins, cross apply and temp tables.

Comment: WHILE way is possible for you?